# Reverse array values while keeping keys

Tags: php, arrays, reverse

Here is an array I have:

```
$a = array('a' => 'a1', 'b' => 'a2', 'c' => 'a3', 'd' => 'a4', 'e' => 'a5');
```

What I would like to do is reverse the values of the array while keeping the keys intact, in other words it should look like this:

```
$a = array('a' => 'a5', 'b' => 'a4', 'c' => 'a3', 'd' => 'a2', 'e' => 'a1');
```

How should I go about it?

P.S.  I tried using `array_reverse()` but it didn't seem to work

Comment: Its pretty cool that this is possible, and down below seeing it as a one liner is also cool. What would be a use case where you want to keep the keys the same but reverse the data?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Some step-by-step processing using native PHP functions (this can be compressed with less variables):

```
$a = array('a' => 'a1', 'b' => 'a2', 'c' => 'a3', 'd' => 'a4', 'e' => 'a5');

$k = array_keys($a);
$v = array_values($a);

$rv = array_reverse($v);

$b = array_combine($k, $rv);

var_dump($b);
```

Result:

```
array(5) {
  'a' =>
  string(2) "a5"
  'b' =>
  string(2) "a4"
  'c' =>
  string(2) "a3"
  'd' =>
  string(2) "a2"
  'e' =>
  string(2) "a1"
}
```

Comment: array_reverse actually has a second argument `preserve keys` which do exactly the same in one call. `$rv = array_reverse($v, true);`

Comment: @lifecoder You are missing the central point of the question: The keys should NOT be reversed, only the values.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible by using `array_combine`, `array_values`, `array_keys` and `array_values`. May seem like an awful lot of functions for a simple task, and there may be easier ways though.

```
array_combine( array_keys( $a ), array_reverse( array_values( $a ) ) );
```

Comment: Your one liner is really neat, thanks for teaching that to me!

Answer (score 1):

Here another way;

```
$keys = array_keys($a);
$vals = array_reverse(array_values($a));
foreach ($vals as $k => $v) $a[$keys[$k]] = $v;
```

Answer (score 0):

This'll do it (just wrote it, [demo here](http://ideone.com/K3NfK3)):

```
<?php
function value_reverse($array)
{
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $reversed_values = array_reverse(array_values($array), true);
    return array_combine($keys, $reversed_values);
}

$a = array('a' => 'a1', 'b' => 'a2', 'c' => 'a3', 'd' => 'a4', 'e' => 'a5');

print_r( value_reverse($a) );
```

Comment: The function had typos, fixed it

Comment: @guidod your edit was correct, but _usually_ suggested edits are rejected. For more discussion on the matter please refer to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252806/when-should-i-edit-something-vs-comment-on-it-if-its-a-relatively-trivial-error) on meta

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work..

```
<?php
$old = array('a' => 'a1', 'b' => 'a2', 'c' => 'a3', 'd' => 'a4', 'e' => 'a5');
$rev = array_reverse($old);

foreach ($old as $key => $value) {
    $new[$key] = current($rev);
    next($rev);
}

print_r($new);
?>
```