# How can I rotate the values of an array whilst keeping the keys the same? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How would you go about rotating the values of an array in php?
For example:

```
array ('bill'=>'bob','marley'=>'mary','jake'=>'jack');
```

so that it rotates the value and keeps the key so it'll become,

```
array ('bill'=>'jack','marley'=>'bob','jake'=>'mary');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like homework, have you tried to solve it on your own? - And if the answer is "yes" then add what you have tried in the question.

Comment: yes I have tried with array_shift() but it shifts the entire key and value on one which is not what I want it to do.

Comment: In my opinion I can do that using `foreach()` try to read the manual about foreach you could use that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse array values while keeping keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370551/reverse-array-values-while-keeping-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the comment at every line for detail

```
$a = array ('bill'=>'bob','marley'=>'mary','jake'=>'jack');
$key = array_keys($a);// get all the keys of array
$value = array_values($a);// get all the value of array
$rev = array_reverse($value);// reverse your value
$new_array = array_combine($key, $rev);// combine array wirh key and reverse value
 print_r($new_array);
```

**OUTPUT**

> Array ( [bill] => jack [marley] => mary [jake] => bob )

Comment: Thanks alot! And thanks for the comments they helped me understand the concept!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PHP array [Shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and a loop:

```
$array = array ('bill'=>'bob','marley'=>'mary','jake'=>'jack');
$keys =array_keys($array);
shuffle($array);
$newArray =  array();
foreach ($keys as $key => $value)
{
   $newArray[$value] = $array[$key];
}
print_r($newArray);
```

**Here is a working [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%20$array%20=%20array%20('bill'=%3E'bob','marley'=%3E'mary','jake'=%3E'jack');%5Cn%20$keys%20=array_keys($array);%5Cn%20shuffle($array);%5Cn%20$newArray%20=%20array();%5Cn%20foreach%20($keys%20as%20$key%20=%3E%20$value)%5Cn%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%20$newArray[$value]%20=%20$array[$key];%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn%20print_r($newArray);%5Cn?%3E)**

Answer (score 0):

There must be an easy way but this is what I came up with:

```
 <?php $arr = array ('bill'=>'bob','marley'=>'mary','jake'=>'jack');
       $reversed = array();
           $i = 4;
        foreach($arr as $key => $val){
            $reversed[$key] = $arr[$i];
            $i--;
        }
     print_r($reversed);
  ?>
```