# select records from sql database order by date DESC, but I want show records in table in date ASC

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have 7 records in a table but I want select only last 5 records sorting by date DESC. And I want to show these records in my table sorting by date ASC.

My Code:

```
$select_record = mysqli_query($con, "select * from table order by date DESC limit 5");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_record)){

$date = $row['date'];

echo "<tr><td>$date<br></td></tr>";
```

Records in My Table like this

```
Date
2014-05-15
2014-04-15
2014-06-15
2014-02-15
2014-07-15
2014-01-15
2014-03-15
```

My code give me result like this

```
Date
2014-07-15
2014-06-15
2014-05-15
2014-04-15
2014-03-15
```

But I want result like this

```
Date
2014-03-15
2014-04-15
2014-05-15
2014-06-15
2014-07-15
```

Comment: Hi, Irfan, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read  careful “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: Might be a silly question but .... why do you ORER BY desc when actually you want ORDER BY asc?

Comment: I think he doesn't want the loop to start counting from the 1st month, but the 3rd. idk i'm confused myself.

Comment: ah, missed that. Perfectly valid reason....

Answer (score 5):

Do second SELECT on top of first one:

```
SELECT t.* FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 5) t 
ORDER BY t.`date` ASC
```

short version:

```
(SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 5) ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Comment: You can even omit the outer SELECT `(select * from table order by date DESC limit 5) ORDER BY \`date\`ASC`, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf441/1

Comment: @VolkerK yes, I was confused by first SELECT before parentheses in your comment, thats why I deleted mine afterwards. :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your while loop:

Instead of doing this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_record)){

$date = $row['date'];

echo "<tr><td>$date<br></td></tr>";

}
```

Try doing this:

```
    create an array that can store your date values retrieved from query 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_record)){

    $date = $row['date'];
    Add $date to the array you created

    }
    Iterate the array from the END to START and print dates .
    {
       echo "<tr><td>$date<br></td></tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store Your dates in **Array** and then use **array_reverse()** PHP Function to get the result in reverse order.

[array_reverse — Return an array with elements in reverse order](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

[Reverse array values while keeping keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370551/reverse-array-values-while-keeping-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$select_record = mysqli_query($con, "select * from table order by date DESC limit 5");

// Sort in chronological order.
usort($select_record, function($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a['db'], $b['db']);
});

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_record)){

$date = $row['date'];

echo "<tr><td>$date<br></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to extract the rows and the reverse the list in PHP land. This would be my solution in your simple case based on the result size.

If you really want to do it without having to store the full result in PHP land you could do it with a sub-select. This would mean replacing your query expression with:

```
$select_record = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM (select * from table order by date DESC limit 5) AS result ORDER BY date");
```

But I would think this to be less maintainable than just reversing the result in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also save your result in array. Then you can use `sort($array);`

[PHP function Sort](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sort.php)