# PHP invert key but keep values in the same order

Tags: php

I have an array

```
'20' => 'bill',
 '47' => 'jack',
 '88' => 'john'
```

how can invert the keys to get

```
'88' => 'bill',
 '47' => 'jack',
 '20' => 'john'
```

but keep the values in the same order

thanks you

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370551/reverse-array-values-while-keeping-keys

Comment: Separate the array into an array of values and of keys, reverse the key array, combine them again…

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_combine and array_reverse and get key by array_keys

```
  $arr = ['20' => 'bill',
          '47' => 'jack',
          '88' => 'john'];


  $newArr = array_combine( array_reverse(array_keys($arr)), $arr );

  print_r($newArr);
```

Output with :

```
 [88] => bill
 [47] => jack
 [20] => john
```

Comment: thanks to all , impossible to flag it as solved , no idea where it is

Comment: you can verified this as answer